# return a return in javascript

Tags: javascript, return, assert

I want to write a `assert()` function in Js. Something like this:

```
assert = function(condition, message) {
    if(condition) {
        console.log(message);
    } else {
        return return;
    }
}
```

But it's not true.
We can write it like this:

```
assert = function(condition, message) {
    if(condition) {
        console.log(message);
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use that like this:

```
function () {
     if(!assert(condition)) { return; }
     //Other Lines
}
```

But it could be better if we were be able to use that like this:

```
assert(condition, 'OK');
```

Is it possible to return a return?
In fact have we any way to use something like to previous line to end a function by a assert?

Update:

> My goal is end a function by a simple `assert(condition)` use, and not
>   with use second conditions like `if(!assert(condition)) { return; }`.

p.s: I'm a newbie.

Comment: Shouldn't `return return;` in your true condition be `return true;`?

Answer (score 4):

How about throwing an exception from assert if not true and otherwise nothing. That way, you can use them as you might be familiar already from other languages.

Code example:

```
assert = function(condition, message) {
    if(condition) {
        console.log(message);
    } else {
        throw "Assertion failed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case can't you just use return assert(condition);

Comment: Hi @ali.: If this or any other answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you just want to write less code. If you want to write lots of asserts then consider having a function that processes your list for you, then you only need to maintain an array of parameters:

```
var list = [
    [condition, 'OK'],
    [condition2, 'OK'],
    [condition3, 'OK'],
    [condition4, 'OK']
];

function runAsserts(asserts){
    for(var i = 0; i < asserts.length; i++){
        if(!assert(asserts[i][0], asserts[i][1])) { 
            return; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just call it with:

```
runAsserts(list);
```